# igualdade de arrays em Java Script

Tags: javascript, array

Boa tarde, tenho este pequeno programa:

```
let oi=[1,2,3,4]

let xau=[]
xau=oi

xau[2]=7
console.log(oi)
```

o meu problema é que quando no console a impressão que sai é:

```
[1,2,7,4]
```

de acordo com o que eu entendo, xau deveria ser uma nova instancia que tem os valores de oi, porém ao modificar xau, tbm modifico oi, se alguem puder me explicar o por que isso está acontecendo e como fazer para que eu possa modificar xau sem modificar oi, fico agradecido

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em Javascript, arrays e objetos são passados por referência. Por isso você pode editar os valores do array `oi` através da variável `xau`, uma vez que ambos apontam para o mesmo array.

Você pode criar uma cópia do array `oi` e atribuir ao `xau` usando o método [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```js
let oi=[1,2,3,4]

let xau=oi.slice()

xau[2]=7
console.log(oi, xau)
```

Comment: mt obrigado, nao sabia que era passado por referencia, me ajudou mt

Comment: A resposta é ótima, inclusive vou votar +1. Mas só me permita uma observação: o valor `0` no `slice` seria desnecessário. Se você omitir os parâmetros (deixar vazio, `slice()`) o valor `0` já é assumido.

Comment: @dvd editado. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 1):

O problema já foi explicado pelo @PanterA, mas para ficar como referência a futuros leitores deixo aqui outra forma de criar uma cópia do array utilizando [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
let xau = oi.concat()
```

O [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) serve para concatenar o array com o que é passado por parâmetro. Não passando nada acaba por receber apenas o array original.

Exemplo:

```js
let oi=[1,2,3,4]

let xau=oi.concat()

xau[2]=7
console.log(oi, xau)
```

Utilizando ES6 e o [*spread operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) consegue fazer a cópia de uma forma ainda mais simples com:

```
let xau = [...oi]
```

Veja a funcionar:

```js
let oi=[1,2,3,4]

let xau= [...oi]

xau[2]=7
console.log(oi, xau)
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma outra forma é usando `.map()`:

```js
let oi=[1,2,3,4]

let xau = oi.map(Number)

xau[2]=7
console.log(oi, xau)
```

O `.map()` irá gerar uma nova array independente com os valores de `oi`.