# JavaScript cria referência quando se trata de atribuir um array a uma outra variável do mesmo tipo?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida sobre um problema que estou tendo (peço desculpas se em algum lugar tiver a resposta, é que eu não encontrei e por isso estou postando).

**Introdução**

Quero exibir alguns chekcBoxes já marcados conforme eu trago do banco de dados, até ai tudo bem, eu uso AngularJS e consigo isso fácil!
Através de um ***ng-repeat*** eu exibo uma lista de escolhas, e dentro de cada item dessa lista eu tenho uma outra lista de ***atributos*** que vem do banco de dados:

```
var listaDeEscolhas = [{id: 0, atributos: []},
    {id: 1, atributos: [{tipo:'visivel'}]},
    {id: 2, atributos: []},
    {id: 3,   atributos: [{tipo:'visivel'}]}];
```

Para a exibição dos checkboxes, eu tenho uma outra lista com possíveis atributos no qual o usuário poderá escolher qual ele quer gravar nessa lista de escolhas:

```
var possiveisAtributos = [
      {description: 'visivel', id: 10},
      {description: 'editavel', id: 13}
    ];
```

Quando eu trago do banco essas informações, eu guardo essa lista de ***possiveisAtributos*** em uma outra lista chamada ***atributosParaMostrar*** dentro de cada item da ***listaDeEscolhas*** para então executar um outro ***ng-repeat** nessa lista e exibir de fato para usuário. Nessa lista que eu vou exibir para o usuário (atributosParaMostrar) eu preciso setar um atributo chamado ***selected*** com *true* para que o checkbox fique marcado conforme o atributo ja tenha vindo do banco, e *false* caso não. Então eu faço o seguinte:

```
for (var x = 0; x < listaDeEscolhas.length; x++) {
  listaDeEscolhas[x].atributosParaMostrar = possiveisAtributos;
  for (var y = 0; y < listaDeEscolhas[x].atributos.length; y++) {
    for (var z = 0; z < listaDeEscolhas[x].atributosParaMostrar.length; z++) {
      if ((listaDeEscolhas[x].atributos[y].tipo==listaDeEscolhas[x].atributosParaMostrar[z].description)){
        listaDeEscolhas[x].atributosParaMostrar[z].selected = true;
      } else {
        listaDeEscolhas[x].atributosParaMostrar[z].selected = false;
      }  
    }  
  }
}
```

Como citado acima, eu guardo uma copia da lista ***possiveisAtributos*** em cada ***listaDeEscolhas*** gerando ***atributosParaMostrar***, em seguida eu verifico se o algum dos itens de ***atributosParaMostrar*** esta contido em atributos da ***listaDeEscolhas*** para então colocar *true* no *selected* ou *false* de cada item de ***atributosParaMostrar***

**Problema**

Depois de executado o código acima todas as listas ***atributosParaMostrar*** de cada lista de escolhas estão com *selected* igual a *true*. Já fiz e refiz isso de diversas maneiras porem sem sucesso, acredito que o javascript esteja passando por referência a lista de possíveis atributos ao invés de atribui-la a lista de atributos para mostrar. Peço desculpas mais uma vez caso algo parecido já tenha em outro lugar e gostaria de uma ajuda/analise sobre a situação apresentada.

Comment: Fazer `=` entre arrays é dizer que são o mesmo array. Isso é de facto sempre por referência. Já existem perguntas com o mesmo problema e por isso esta será uma duplicata. Veja [igualdade de arrays em Java Script](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281037/igualdade-de-arrays-em-java-script/) e [Como posso fazer uma copia de um array sem referencia?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82386/como-posso-fazer-uma-copia-de-um-array-sem-referencia).

Comment: Dê uma olhada também nessa pergunta que esse assunto é discutido lá: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286125/como-fazer-passagem-por-valor-em-javascript/